# hindi bolnagri keyboard, type halant without doing a sandhi on linux

Tags: typing-break

I am using a hindi keyboard and I would like to know if its possible to type the halant character without doing a sandhi or joining of 2 letters ?

I tried typing adbhut word in hindi where the d has a halant. But it ends up joining the letters da and bha
like this :
अद्भुत

I dont want this , many words use halant without joining two words. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, I found the answer, at

https://scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=entry_detail&uid=d6dvcx2lay

again. where it clearly states about the zero-width non-joiner key (U+200C) accessed by letter q in hindi bolnagri keyboard.

I can now type : अद्‌भुत , सद्‌गुरु  etc